# Find serial ports

Tags: java

I have searched for code that can represent the serial ports I have on. I found this one:

```
Enumeration pList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

// Process the list.CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("/dev/tty1");
while (pList.hasMoreElements()) {
  CommPortIdentifier cpi = (CommPortIdentifier) pList.nextElement();

  System.out.print("Port " + cpi.getName() + " ");
  if (cpi.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
    System.out.println("is a Serial Port: " + cpi);
  } else if (cpi.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL) {
    System.out.println("is a Parallel Port: " + cpi);
  } else {
    System.out.println("is an Unknown Port: " + cpi);
  }
}
```

but it isn't working, it seems that pList doesn't have any elements.
Maybe my computer doesn't have any serial ports, in this case how can I check it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find a COM port via CommPortIdentifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786432/how-to-find-a-com-port-via-commportidentifier)

Comment: How do you know pList has no elements? Are you using a debugger? If you're going based solely on print statements are there any exceptions thrown?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the **RXTX** library, the following should provide a list of available COM ports on your machine:

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  Enumeration thePorts = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
  while (thePorts.hasMoreElements())
  {
     CommPortIdentifier com = (CommPortIdentifier) thePorts.nextElement();
     switch (com.getPortType())
     {
        case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
           list.add(com.getName());
     }
  }
```

You can check your available COM ports in Windows by using the *device manager*. Navigate to `Ports (COM & LPT)`. Most desktop computers will have `COM1` available. Other devices, such as USB Virtual COM ports, will also be displayed in the list, if they exist.

**RXTX** has pretty specific instructions for installation. Those instructions can be found [here](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Using_RXTX).

Typically, you must perform the following:

1. copy the `rxtxSerial.dll` and `rxtxParallel.dll` to your `JRE/bin` directory. In Windows this would be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin` or something similar based on your computer.
2. Then you must copy the `rxtx` JAR file to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext`.

*Note: If you're running in an IDE like Netbeans, you may have to place these files under your `JDK/jre`.*

Comment: Thank you very much !!!! have the nicest week ever! :) , another small question every computer have those ports ,laptops have then to ?

Comment: You're welcome - BTW welcome to SO! If this answer worked for you, please select it as the answer to the question.

Comment: `COM1` generally refers to a physical port on the computer (as opposed to a USB Virtual COM port). If the computer has a physical serial port it should have `COM1` available regardless of whether its a laptop or a desktop.

Comment: Sorry for bothering but i have an error when i run this "program,java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver" is the error that jumps ,do you have any ideas why ? i added the rxtx api to the project ,but i dont have the gnu ,should i add it to the project to ?

Comment: @user3194834 Remember that if this answer was useful to you, then you should mark it as the accepted answer (the green check mark below the answer score)

Comment: @user3194834 I have updated my answer to provide some instructions for installation. Normally, you should open up another question to be answered about how to install RXTX.

Comment: @user3194834 The instruction link was incorrect. My apologies. The correct link has been updated in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jSerialComm](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/) library. It's pure java and does not require extra native libs.

```
SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
for (SerialPort port: ports)
    System.out.println(port.getSystemPortName());
```