# List all serial port in java

Tags: java, serial-port, modbus

I have created an application in java for Modbus hardware device. I can install my application on Windows system which works fine. But I am facing Issue when I tried to use  my application Linux operating system. The reason behind this issue is serial port, because of which I am not able to connect my application with the hardware other than Windows operating system. Now I want to find the list of serial ports(operating system wise) & add them into the JComboBox at the place of comport(refer below image).
I need to distribute this application on Windows, Linux, MacOS.
I can detect the operating system through my code. I have checked a lot resources, but none of them were useful to me.

Need some help to detect the serial port of the system.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Connection establishment page]

Comment: By Serial Ports do you mean the list of all available networks on that Machine? I mean Network Interfaces?

Comment: @notescrew, Only external ports through which I can connect my device with USB cable.

Comment: maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120955/find-serial-ports can help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code might help you. It will give you the list of connected devices at serial port.
Use https://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/ library to run this code.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SerialPort[] ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (SerialPort port : ports) {
            System.out.println(port.getSystemPortName());
            list.add(port.getSystemPortName());
        }
        System.out.println("List of serial port is : "+list);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have found this answer useful, accept this answer.