# Connect to USB using java

Tags: java, windows, usb

Good morning all,
i'm trying to connect to a USB device from Java in Windows.

I need it to read some data from a USB cable.

Here is my code:

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM03");
            serialPort.openPort();
            serialPort.setParams(4800, 8, 1, 0);//Set params.
            while(true) {
                byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(10);
                if(buffer!=null) {
                    for(byte b:buffer) {
                        System.out.print(b);
                    }
                } 
            }
        } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that Java doesn't accept to connect whatever the SerialPort name is.

I tried with COM 1-2000 in COM1 or COM01 format. Nothing to do. Java ever raises an exception

> Port name - COM3; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port not found.

If I put in the port name a slash (e.g. "xxxxx\"), whatever xxxxx is, the error becomes

> Port name - COM3; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port busy.

To start i'm trying to connect to my optical mouse...only for starting.

Thanks to who can help me.

I tried to connect to a USB device and I expected to read the data from it

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64890242/list-all-serial-port-in-java

Comment: USB doesn't work like you think it does. You __cannot__ connect to your optical mouse because your optical mouse is __not a serial device__. USB has profiles and a USB device tells the host system what profiles it supports. One such profile is 'serial connection'. A device such as an arduino supports such a profile. I have no idea what happens on windows, but it's plausible it'll result in a virtual COM port. The actual `COM1` designation is rooted in actual COM ports. To find one of those you need to put on your indiana jones hat, and raid a museum. All of this is virtual these days.

Comment: My goal is to use raw wires to receive impulses (I have a peripheral that communicates via pulses...so i thought to link these wire transmitting pulses directly into the IN wire of the USB cable.
how can I let Java or Python read these kind of configuration?
Can somebody help me with hardware and code?
Thanks